# How to get screen resolution in ruby

Tags: ruby, screen, resolution

How to get screen resolution (height, width) in ruby script?

Comment: In what units?  The kind returned by `ˋstty sizeˋ`?

Comment: What Operational System?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

```
x, y = `xrandr`.scan(/current (\d+) x (\d+)/).flatten
```

On windows, use [WIN32OLE and such](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/92264).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved my problem of getting resolution. As I was using Ruby 2.3.0, I cannot use DL module(as its been depricated). Following is by using Fiddle

```
usr32=Fiddle::dlopen("user32")
gsm=Fiddle::Function.new(usr32["GetSystemMetrics"],[Fiddle::TYPE_LONG],Fiddle::TYPE_LONG)
x= gsm.call(0)
y= gsm.call(1)
puts x,y
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has no notion of a GUI. You would need to use somethign like the [Ruby Xlib Wrapper](http://ruby-xlib-wrap.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using [`tput`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php),
e.g.

```
cols  = %x[tput cols].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page while looking for solutions on how to deal with multi-monitor setups, so I'll add what I found here. For me the best solution was using Qt, which can be done as follows:

```
require 'Qt4'

desktop = Qt::DesktopWidget.new
desktop.screenGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen)
```

The object returned by `screenGeometry` is a `QRect` which has height, width and [a whole bunch of other potentially useful attributes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.2/qrect.html). Obviously this is specifically for the primary screen, but you could also use `desktop.numScreens` to determine how many screens there are and check them all individually.

I realise this question is old, but hopefully this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ruby Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/92264)

```
require 'dl/import'
require 'dl/struct'

SM_CXSCREEN =   0
SM_CYSCREEN =   1

user32 = DL.dlopen("user32")

get_system_metrics = user32['GetSystemMetrics', 'ILI']
x, tmp = get_system_metrics.call(SM_CXSCREEN,0)
y, tmp = get_system_metrics.call(SM_CYSCREEN,0)

puts "#{x} x #{y}"
```